# Would SQL Server use Merge Join with Non clustered index or Merge join need Clustered Index only?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I was just wondering if SQL Server can choose to use `MERGE JOIN` if both the tables has `Non Clustered Index` on joining columns and columns included in SELECT list is also a part of non clustered index.

I know prerequisite for a MERGE JOIN is joining columns must be sorted. Does that mean clustered index only?

Comment: A `MERGE JOIN` needs to have **sorted inputs** in order to work. **Any index** is sorted by definition - nonclustered or clustered - so both types of indexes should be capable of supporting a `MERGE JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonclustered index can be used to perform the merge join. Only pre-requite is that the joining columns matches the index column order.

try this.

```
DROP TABLE snapshot 
CREATE TABLE snapshot (id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,batchid INT,sqltime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO snapshot(sqltime,batchid) VALUES('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1 ),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3),
('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3)


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_snapshot_Non_Clustered ON snapshot(batchid)include(sqltime)

SELECT * FROM snapshot s1 INNER MERGE JOIN snapshot s2 on S1.batchid = s2.batchid
```

In the Execution plan for the above query you can see that the Merge Join is on the non clustered index and not the clustered index on id.

[image: Query PLan]

Comment: You explicitly mentioned MERGE in join operation which is why example shows Merge join. I can see sort operation is not used and sql server is using NC index. Did you use it just because example has less data?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Yes, Since my example has less data, SQL Server would have most likely used nested join if i didnt explicitly mention MERGE query hint. I added MERGE explicitly to replicate the question and to show that a merge join can happen on NC index and also without a sort operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can use a nonclustered index to perform a merge join without an explicit sort step as long as the key columns are in an order that ensures the columns used in the join predicate are in the required sort order.